# firebase / вывести поле с одним названием из всех документов

Tags: javascript, firebase, firestore

структура следующая, пишу на js [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в коллекции "values"  надо обратиться к полю "income", которое есть в каждом документе, а далее вывести сумму этих полей(они в числовом формате).

Не понимаю как сделать обращение ко всем документам.

Answer (score 0):

```
let valuesSumm = 0;

db.collection("values").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    valuesSumm += doc.data().income;
  });
});

console.log(valuesSumm);
```